# if statement not working correctly? JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, npm

I am currently using an array for a menu and using if statements for each option. The problem i have found is if the first option i select uses an if statement that is below an option i ask later, it doesn't give a result.

For example. If i add credit, and then the next option i select to view current credit, it does not complete that task and shows nothing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Kind Regards.

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync')
var credit = 0;
var removeCredit = 0;

menu = [];
menu[0] = "Purchase a product";
menu[1] = "View your credit";
menu[2] = "Add credit";
menu[3] = "Retrieve a refund";

index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');

if (index == [1]) {
console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £", credit);
index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');
}

if (index == [2]) {
var credit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you like to purchase? ');
console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £" + (credit));
index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');
}

if (index == [3]) {
var removeCredit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you like to remove? ');
console.log("This credit has now been removed, your total available credit is: £" + (credit - removeCredit));
index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');
}
```

Comment: What does keyInSelect method returns ? a number ?

Comment: Yes, it displays the array with a number next to each element and asks the user to input which option they want to choose.

Comment: If the method is returning a number, you should check the variable against a number, Why are you checking against [1] instead of 1 ?

Comment: @Shyju...That's not supposed to be a problem.It's the same thing.

Comment: `[1] === [1]; // false` because two different object instances are never equal

Comment: Where is this code placed exactly?Is it in a function or loop?

Comment: That's the code as it is at the moment for the menu/array. I am just trying to get all options working correctly before moving forward.

Comment: I would start by declaring index on the top. It could be a hoisting issue. E.g. var index;

Comment: readlineSync is a console method from NPM. Are you sure you need that or is this a client JS question?

Comment: No....the previous code cannot be checked again coz the control has already moved ahead.Use a function(put the conditional statements in this function) so that you call it again and all the previous statements will also be checked.

Comment: To clarify, this code is being run on console.

Comment: You must use a loop or function to reuse the previous code.It doesn't matter if you are using a console or command centre.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is to loop your script:

```
var index, credit, removeCredit;
while(true) {
    index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');
    if (index == 1) {
        console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £", credit);
    }

    if (index == 2) {
       credit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you to purchase? ');
        console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £" + (credit));
    }

    if (index == 3) {
       removeCredit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you like to remove? ');
       console.log("This credit has now been removed, your total available credit is: £" + (credit - removeCredit));
    }
}
```

To get out of the loop with an option:

```
var index, credit, removeCredit;
while(index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option') != 4) {
    if (index == 1) {
        console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £", credit);
    }

    if (index == 2) {
       credit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you to purchase? ');
        console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £" + (credit));
    }

    if (index == 3) {
       removeCredit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you like to remove? ');
       console.log("This credit has now been removed, your total available credit is: £" + (credit - removeCredit));
    }
}
```

Where `4` is the option to get out. Notice too that I'm using "loose" equality, just because I don't really know if `keyInSelect` returns a number or a string.

I think syntax is kind of awkward (specially assignment and comparison in while condition) so here's another version.

```
var index, credit, removeCredit;
do {
   index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(menu, 'Please choose your option');
   switch(index) {
      case 1:
          console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £", credit);
      break;

      case 2:
          credit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you to purchase? ');
          console.log("The total amount of credit you have is: £" + (credit));
      break;

      case 3:
          removeCredit = readlineSync.questionInt('How much credit would you like to remove? ');
          console.log("This credit has now been removed, your total available credit is: £" + (credit - removeCredit));
      break;

   }
} while(index != 4)
```

Comment: This does allow me to use earlier options such as view the credit after adding credit. But then the meu/array options are in a constant loop. There is a CANCEL option which is shown too, but even selecting that just loops it again.

Comment: I didn't see any cancel option there, but it's possible to add it.

Comment: Ahh ok, yes the cancel option is displayed as default within the menu in console. How would i add an option into the loop to leave the menu, therefore just terminating it? All other options are working now, but i really need a way to exist the loop and leave the menu. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just add a new element to the `menu` array. "Quit". It should appear as `[4] Quit`. Then user just types 4 and quits.

Comment: Ahh yes! The third option worked great for allowing it to quit the loop, although i have noticed if i add credit (say 10), remove the credit, which it does correctly and then check the credit again it shows what i added originally (10). It must be because of the loop, but thanks for helping me learn where i have gone wrong :)

Comment: @ZenoX, it is because you are not saving the substraction to `credit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the brackets in your if statements, like so:

```
if (index == 1)
```

Comment: It's not the root of the problem though... as `var index = 1; index == [1] //true`. There's really no reason to compare it like this though.

Comment: That still produces the same error if selecting an option from an earlier if statement. Nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple enough.The previous `if` statements will not be considered as the control cannot move back.
You should enter all these `if` statements in a `function`.
Whenever a new input is taken,call this function so that each and every `if` statement is checked.Control moves from one line to the next and it does not move back to a previous line unless it is in a function(call it) or loop.

If you use a function,you can call the function again and each and every `if` statement will be checked again.

eg:

```
if(i==1)
alert("one");
if(i==2)
alert("two");
 i=1;
if(i==3)
alert("three");
```

Control cannot back to the previous `if` statement.So no popup will be shown.

```
function alerts()
{

if(i==1)
alert("one");
if(i==2)
alert("two");
 i=1;
alerts();
if(i==3)
}
```

In this case an alert box with one pop up coz the function is called and therefore,the previous statements are also checked.